# Android setting button margins programmatically with multiple buttons does not work

Tags: android, button, margin

I am currently trying to implement an Android app that has 6 buttons for one activity. While I am trying to set the button margin programmatically, when there is only one buton, without any problem it sets. However when I try it with multiple buttons, all of them are set on the upper left corner of the app. I don't know what to do, so any help will be appreaciated. 
Here is the layout and activity codes:

```
private void initializeUIElements() 
{

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    playButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.play_button));

    final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpt =(MarginLayoutParams)playButton.getLayoutParams();
    lpt.setMargins((int)(width/2.4),(height/4),(int)(width/2.4),(height/4));
    playButton.setLayoutParams(lpt);

    facebookButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.facebook_button));
    lpt.setMargins(100,400,380,400);
    facebookButton.setLayoutParams(lpt);

    t = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.textView1));
    t.setText(width + " " + height);



    twitterButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.twitter_button));
    topTenButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.top_ten_button));
    yayinAkisiButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.yayin_akisi_button));
    son5Button = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.son_5_button));


    playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    facebookButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    twitterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    topTenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    yayinAkisiButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    son5Button.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Here is the XML Layout codes:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Facebook" 
    android:onClick="true"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/son_5_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Son 5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/yayin_akisi_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yayın Akışı" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/top_ten_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TopTen" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/twitter_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Twitter" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="193dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key piece of information you are missing is that because you are using a RelativeLayout, you must specify rules for how each button will appear relative to the other.

Please modify your XML like this:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Facebook" 
android:onClick="true"
android:layout_below="@id/main_bg"   (this is what you are missing)
/>
```

RelativeLayouts have all sorts of capabilities.  See this page for more info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Chances are, you might prefer a different layout, such as a LinearLayout in vertical mode.  Assuming you are using Eclipse, play around with the UI and you'll find a way to convert your RelativeLayout (which is the default) to a LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look at it as soon as I got home. Actually my main problem is to set buttons to the specific ideas on my background, (also they must remain for different screen sizes) that's why I try to set the buttons programmatically.

Comment: I'm afraid it did not work Steven. Also whole buttons disappeared, since you wrote android:layout_below="@id/main_bg"

Comment: it's possible that your ImageView is hogging the screen.  Change the width and height to something fixed.